# Cypher: Match All Elements In A Collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a collection of element ids.  I am currently using an UNWIND to find nodes that match at least one element.

```
UNWIND ids as id
MATCH (e:Element)-[]-(f:Foo {id:id})
RETURN DISTINCT e
```

I wanted to find out how I could find the elements that match ALL the ids.  Such that if I have 5 ids, the elements that have a relation to all 5 matching nodes and exclude nodes that only match 1 or 2.

I was thinking I could do something with COUNT and pass in the number of elements as a query parameter, but that seemed pretty hacky.

Does anyone know how to do return nodes that match all elements in a collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there only a single relationship between `Element` and `Foo` nodes? If so, how about comparing the number of ids you have to the number of relationships connecting each distinct `Element` to `Foo` nodes:

```
UNWIND ids AS id
MATCH (e:Element)-[r]->(f:Foo {id: id})
WITH e, COUNT(r) AS num WHERE num = SIZE(ids)
RETURN e
```

Comment: Supplementing, this and other approaches are discussed in this [knowledge base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did not find that when I was searching.  Definitely some good tips and info in there!